# How To Access Firebase Databese add?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working in web app user data store. I face the problem in when I connecting in database on firebasae cloudhost,then this code solve the problem. I'm shear in Code.`enter code here

`````
const tableUser =document.querySelector('.table-users')

const renderUser=doc => {
const tr =`
<tr data-id=${doc.id}>
<td>${doc.data().FristName}</td>
<td>${doc.data().LastName}</td>
<td>${doc.data().Phone}</td>
<td>${doc.data().Email}</td>
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-edit">Edid</button>
    <button class="btn btn-delete">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>`;
tableUser.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',tr);


db.collection('users').get().then(querySnapshot =>{
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
        renderUser(doc)

    });
});



addModalform.addEventListener('submit',e =>{
e.preventDefault();
db.collection('users').add({
    FristName:addModalform.FristName.value,
    LastName:addModalform.LastName.value,
    Phone:addModalform.Phone.value,
    Email:addModalform.Email.value,
});
});````
That the code in write in Solve that my Connection Firebase,I hope help all are tham.
`````

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

my problem is I'm not Confram connected my firebase databese, then this code write in it's solve that. now i'm shear js code , then Now it's working